# Two attached hibernate object referring to same data, which one will be saved?

Tags: java, hibernate

In one  hibernate session.

I first get an object, say A, by retrieving one record using session.get(id, class),  I made some change to object A.

Then I made a search using criteria.list() to get an objects list which contains object B referring to the same data object A refers to.  I also made some change to object B.

After I commit the session, which change i made will be persisted to database, A or B or both?

Answer (score 0):

> Every time you fetch something from the Database it created a new
>   object. Even if the value of the object is the same it is internally
>   different.
>
> In the case if you are fetching values only once and creating a copy
>   of the object then it just create a reference to the object, so any
>   change in the first will be reflected to the second too.
>
> When you commit the changes the value of the last object saved, will
>   be the value inside the table. The reason for that is, the value of
>   the previous object was saved first and its been overwritten by the
>   second.

Answer (score 0):

None! You will get an exception saying: *org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session* unless you manually manage them using `merge()` method.